# F#: wrap single element to array

Tags: f#

in F#, How to make a function `wrapper (x:'T)` to wrap any inputs to an array of array, say: `wrapper(1) = [|[|1|]|]; wrapper([|1|]) = [|[|1|]|]; and wrapper([|[|1|]|]) = [|[|1|]|];` something like below does not work:

```
let wrapper (x:'T) = 
    let y = 
        if not <| x.GetType().IsArray then [|[|x|]|]
        elif not <| x.[0].GetType().IsArray then [|x|]
        else x
    y
```

Comment: If you want to do this in F#, you are probably doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, that's not a well-typed function (try to write out the type signature).

Comment: thanks. Would a dynamic type language like python allow such functions?

Comment: @matlabdbuser - any .NET language can do much of what a typical dynamic language can do using `System.Reflection`. And now, with the DLR in .NET 4.0 together with built-in language features like C#'s static `dynamic` and F#'s `?` operator, the gap is even tighter.

Comment: @matlabdbuser - As some of the other answers have shown, it is possible to get this to work in F# as long as you give the function a relatively uninformative type (e.g. `obj->obj`, or `'a -> 'b[][]`).  To me, the question is why you would want a function that does this.  When you're fighting this hard against the type system, it's usually an indication that there's a more idiomatic way to solve your problem if you step back and analyze your requirements.

Comment: @kvb - if I want to make a fuction to tranform any inputs of `string[],string[][], float[],float[][],int[],int[][],bool[],bool[][], whatever...` to a typed `datatable`, and for 1d array `'t[]` I want it to fill the datatable by one column instead of one row, I figured it would be handy to get a wrapper function as in my question ?

Answer (score 4):

The following seems to work:

```
let wrapper<'a, 'b> (x:'a) = 
  match box x with
  | null -> null
  | :? array<array<'b>> as y -> y
  | :? array<'b> as y -> [|y|]
  | y -> [|[|unbox y|]|]
```

The signature is `'a -> array<array<'b>>`.

In response to your comment: this sort of thing can be done in statically-typed languages--and, arguably better than in a dynamic language--but/because stepping outside the type system must be explicit (e.g., `box`/`unbox`).

Answer (score 2):

Here's a reflection based solution which will accept inputs of arbitrary nested array depth:

```
open System.Text.RegularExpressions
let wrapper input =
    let ty = input.GetType()
    if ty.IsArray |> not then
        [|[|input |> unbox|]|]
    else
        let depth = Regex.Matches(ty.Name, "\[\]", RegexOptions.Compiled).Count
        let rec findInnerItem curDepth curArray =
            let innerItem = curArray.GetType().GetMethod("Get").Invoke(curArray, [|box 0|])
            if curDepth = depth then
                innerItem
            else
                findInnerItem (curDepth+1) innerItem

        let innerItem = findInnerItem 1 input
        [|[|innerItem |> unbox|]|]
```

Usage in FSI:

```
val wrapper : 'a -> 'b [] []

> let x : int[][] = wrapper 1;;

val x : int [] [] = [|[|1|]|]

> let x : int[][] = wrapper [|1|];;

val x : int [] [] = [|[|1|]|]

> let x : int[][] = wrapper [|[|1|]|];;

val x : int [] [] = [|[|1|]|]

> let x : int[][] = wrapper [|[|[|1|]|]|];;

val x : int [] [] = [|[|1|]|]

> let x : int[][] = wrapper [|[|[|[|1|]|]|]|];;

val x : int [] [] = [|[|1|]|]

> let x : int[][] = wrapper [|[|[|[|[|1|]|]|]|]|];;

val x : int [] [] = [|[|1|]|]

> let x : int[][] = wrapper [|[|[|[|[|[|1|]|]|]|]|]|];;

val x : int [] [] = [|[|1|]|]
```

Answer (score -1):

You function needs to "wrap any inputs to an array of array". As par this statement the solution is as simple as:

```
let wrapper (x:'T) = [|[|x|]|];
```

But then the examples you have given are not as par your function definition.
i.e `wrapper([|1|]) = [|[|1|]|]`  should be `wrapper([|1|]) = [|[|[|1|]|]|]` as par your function definition.